# Functional invariance of exponential stochastic order

Tags: actuarial-science, moment-generating-functions

I am studying for an exam on stochastic order. I am struggling with a question on functional invariance of exponential order ($\leq_{\mathrm{e}}$), where for r.v.s $X$ and $Y$, $$X \leq_{\mathrm{e}} Y \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{\iff}m_X(t) \leq m_Y(t), \qquad t>0,$$
where $m_X(t)$ is the moment generating function of $X$.

I need to prove that for any nondecreasing function $f(\cdot)$,
$$ X \leq_{\mathrm{e}} Y \implies f(X) \leq_{\mathrm{e}} f(Y),$$
or give a counterexample.

My attempt was this:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nondecreasing function, i.e. $$ \forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R},\; x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y). $$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $X \leq_{\mathrm{e}} Y$.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}[e^{tX}] \leq \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}[e^{tY}] & \implies \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}[e^{tf(X)}] \leq \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}[e^{tf(Y)}] \tag{$\ast$}\\
&\implies m_{f(X)}(t) \leq m_{f(Y)}(t)\\
&\implies f(X) \leq_{\mathrm{e}}f(Y).
\end{align}

However I am not convinced that the implication in $(\ast)$ is actually true. The reasoning looks too ‘simple’. I am not even confident the proof holds at all. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Your implication is not true. If the whole statement is true or not I am not sure, but if a proof exists it will depend on the fact that $m_x(t) \leq m_Y(t) \forall t>0$. Notice that in your proof you basically look at fixed $t$.

Comment: A counter example would be to take to normal random variables with mean zero and different variances. Then take $f$ such that you transform them into lognormal random variables. The moment generating function of a lognormal is undefined, so the comparison doesn't even make sense in that case.